# how to check for the 1st element and last element in array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, element

Compute the smoothed array by doing this: Each value `smooth[N]` is
the average of three values: `signal[N-1]`, `signal[N]`, and `signal[N+1]`.

For the first element of
smooth, average the first two elements of signal. For the last element of smooth, average the
last two elements of signal.

How do I check for the 1st element and last element? Is using a `for`-loop wrong? Here is what my function looks like.

```
void smoothArray(const int sig[], int result[], int len)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {

        result[i] = (sig[i - 1] + sig[i] + sig[i + 1]) / 3;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting the value of `sig[i-1]` to be when `i=0`?

Comment: and `sig[i+1]` when `i=len`?

Comment: @elimad thats the first element right? I don't no how to set the first and last element to find the average of the first two element in the second array.

Comment: Nope. That is invalid as `0-1 = -1`. Can there be negative subscripts for an array? You please get the C++ basics right. There are so many excellent resources available.

Comment: i=0 in the second array. sig[i-1] is the element before sig[i] in the first array @elimad

Comment: Victor, the person you're responding to apparently didn't read the problem explanation. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void smoothArray(const int sig[], int result[], int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        // first elem
        if (0 == i){
            result[i] = (sig[1] + sig[0]) / 2;
            continue;
        }

        // last elem
        if (len - 1 == i){
            result[i] = (sig[i] + sig[i - 1]) / 2;
            continue;
        }

        result[i] = (sig[i - 1] + sig[i] + sig[i + 1]) / 3;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank You @user3823825 and @JimBalter.

To check for the first element and last and average of two element in a different array, a for loop with two if statements is needed.

```
void smoothArray(const int sig[], int result[], int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        // first elem
        if (0 == i){
            result[i] = (sig[1] + sig[0]) / 2;
            continue;
        }

        // last elem
        if (len - 1 == i){
            result[i] = (sig[i] + sig[i - 1]) / 2;
            continue;
        }

        result[i] = (sig[i - 1] + sig[i] + sig[i + 1]) / 3;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine the first or the last element if the param *len* is the length of *result* array.

The function should be

```
void smoothArray(const int sig[], int result[], int lenSig, int lenResult)
```

Comment: The function was given to me. I cant't Change it.

Comment: Maybe the length of the array *sig* is equal to the length of the array *result*.They are all equal to *len*.

Comment: Yes this is true... the rest of the my code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394569/function-that-returns-average

Comment: void smoothArray(const int sig[], int result[], int len)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
      // first elem
      if (0 == i){
       result[i] = (sig[1] + sig[0]) / 2;
       continue;
      }
      
      if (len - 1 == i){
       result[i] = (sig[i] + sig[i - 1]) / 2;
       continue;
      }
      
            result[i] = (sig[i - 1] + sig[i] + sig[i + 1]) / 3;
        }
        return;
    }

Comment: @user3823825: you may edit your answer instead of adding code in comment.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check for the 1st element and last element?

By testing your loop index to see if it's the first or last index of the array:

```
void smoothArray(const int sig[], int result[], int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
         int sum = sig[i], n = 1;
         if (i > 0)
             sum += sig[i-1], n++;
         if (i < len-1)
             sum += sig[i+1], n++;

         result[i] = sum / n;
    }
}
```